# Windows Phone images in another project XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have images in another project in Visual Studio for my Windows Phone App. I have referenced them with the code below, and they appear in the visual studio designer just fine. They do not appear on the emulator. I have tried both Content and Embedded Resource... as well as Do Not Copy, and Copy Always.  Does anyone know what should be used?

```
<Image Height="72" Width="72" Source="/MyApp.Common;component/Assets/Images/FacebookSquare.png" >
```

Comment: Did you try it with your device?

Comment: I have a project that I embed in all my applications. In that project I have image assets that I sometimes use. The way that you are referencing it seems to be the same way I do in my apps. It should work in both emulator and phone identically in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then link the actual files into the project, but let them reside in the foreign project. Here is how that is done in Visual Studio:

1. In the assets folder of the WP8 phone project right click and select `Add` then `Existing Item...` or <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Browse to the location of the image(s) found in the other project and select the file(s).
3. Once the item(s) have been selected, then on the `Add` button select the drop down arrow.
4. Select `Add as link` to add the image(s) as a link into the folder. At this point the file is included in the project as if it actually existed locally, but it exists (and can be changed remotely and that change will be brought over) in a separate location.

   [image]
5. Reference the image properly in the Xaml to the Assets folder of the current project.

Once built it should be included in the final build, if not check its include property setting as you mentioned to `Copy Always`.

Comment: @creative This method is also used when entities reside in a server project and you want those same entities to be in your client application (primarily web based here). By using the `add as link` any changes on server side are reflected in the client project as well. This is an old Silverlight trick because one can't pull in differing CLRs assemblies for a Silverlight codebase from a different version CLR .net Server code.